# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver on new docker container

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, jdbc, camunda

I am trying to create a docker image with Sql server JDBC Driver.

However I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@71423665;ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@71423665
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:281)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38)
        ... 42 more
```

My Docker file is like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.10 as builder

ARG VERSION=7.12.0
ARG DISTRO=tomcat
ARG SNAPSHOT=true

ARG EE=false
ARG USER
ARG PASSWORD

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        ca-certificates \
        maven \
        tar \
        wget \
        xmlstarlet

COPY settings.xml download.sh camunda-tomcat.sh camunda-wildfly.sh  /tmp/

RUN /tmp/download.sh


##### FINAL IMAGE #####

FROM alpine:3.10

ARG VERSION=7.12.0

#MSSQL SERVER JDBC DRIVER INSTALL
COPY sqljdbc_7.4.1.0_enu.tar.gz /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN tar -xf sqljdbc_7.4.1.0_enu.tar.gz
RUN export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/tmp/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar"

ENV CAMUNDA_VERSION=${VERSION}
ENV DB_DRIVER=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
ENV DB_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://xx.database.windows.net:1433;database=camundadb;user=demo@xx;password=xxx.;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
ENV DB_USERNAME=
ENV DB_PASSWORD=
ENV DB_CONN_MAXACTIVE=20
ENV DB_CONN_MINIDLE=5
ENV DB_CONN_MAXIDLE=20
ENV DB_VALIDATE_ON_BORROW=false
ENV DB_VALIDATION_QUERY="SELECT 1"
ENV SKIP_DB_CONFIG=
ENV WAIT_FOR=
ENV WAIT_FOR_TIMEOUT=120
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV DEBUG=TRUE
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"

EXPOSE 8080 8000



# Downgrading wait-for-it is necessary until this PR is merged
# https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/pull/68
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        bash \
        ca-certificates \
        openjdk11-jre-headless \
        tzdata \
        tini \
        xmlstarlet \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh \
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/a454892f3c2ebbc22bd15e446415b8fcb7c1cfa4/wait-for-it.sh" \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S camunda && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S camunda -G camunda -h /camunda -s /bin/bash -D camunda
WORKDIR /camunda
USER camunda

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD ["./camunda.sh"]

COPY --chown=camunda:camunda --from=builder /camunda .
```

**Update 1:**

I removed the export line and added:

ENV CLASSPATH ${CLASSPATH}:/tmp/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar
ARG CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/tmp/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar

based on other SO questions, I tried also the jre11 and jre12 versions of the driver, but still have the same error, unable to load class.

**Update 2:**

According to Camunda documentation here: https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform

Java Versions
Our docker images are using the latest LTS OpenJDK version supported by Camunda BPM. This currently means:

Camunda 7.12 will be based on OpenJDK 11
All previous versions are based on OpenJDK 8

According to Microsoft documentation here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/system-requirements-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017

**Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.4 for SQL Server:**

The JDBC Driver 7.4 includes three JAR class libraries in each installation package: mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar, mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre11.jar, and mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar.

The JDBC Driver 7.4 is designed to work with and be supported by all major Java virtual machines, but is tested only on OpenJDK 1.8, OpenJDK 11.0, OpenJDK 12.0, Azul Zulu JRE 1.8, Azul Zulu JRE 11.0, and Azul Zulu JRE 12.0.

version 7.4 is supported by OpenJDK

Comment: Most ways of running Java applications will not use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable at all.

Comment: any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Possibly coping the driver to the tomcat `lib` folder instead will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that `RUN export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/tmp/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar"` will has no effect in your `dockerfile`:

instead you need to use `ENV` for runtime and `ARG` for build:

```
ENV CLASSPATH ${CLASSPATH}:/tmp/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar
ARG CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/tmp/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar
```

Comment: do you build the image again ? make sure that you have new build from scratch

Comment: will these comands above delete the previous classpath instead of appending it?

Comment: You must make sure that the CLASSPATH statement contains only one Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server, add echo $CLASSPATH after your `ENV` to see what comes ....

Comment: please try also to copy the jar file to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib/`

Answer (score 0):

For the people searching how to get the mssql-jdbc driver working with Camunda.

I did it using the default docker image and extended it using a Dockerfile.

Dowload the driver from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server

Create a Dockerfile with contents:

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:${CAMUNDA_VERSION:-7.18.0-SNAPSHOT}

#MSSQL SERVER JDBC DRIVER INSTALL
COPY sqljdbc_11.2.0.0_enu.tar.gz /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN tar -xf sqljdbc_11.2.0.0_enu.tar.gz

RUN mv /tmp/sqljdbc_11.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre11.jar /camunda/lib/mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre11.jar

WORKDIR /camunda
```

offcourse the filenames can vary based on the jdbc version u are using.